# Download multiple images from multiple canvas elements on single click

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

while downloading images i am able to append images from canvas data to document body but only the last image gets downloaded why?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas');
 for(var i=0; i<canvas.length; i++){
  function doCanvas(){
    ctx = canvas[i].getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = '#f90';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas[i].width, canvas[i].height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.font = '30px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillText('Canvas_'+i, 10, canvas[i].height / 2 - 15);
  }
  doCanvas();
 }

 document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', downloadCanvas, false);
function downloadCanvas() {
    for(var j=0; j < canvas.length; j++){
    this.href = canvas[j].toDataURL();
     var im = document.createElement('img');
     im.src=this.href;
     document.body.appendChild(im);
    this.download = 'test'+j+'.png';
  }
 }
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="100" class="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas width="300" height="100" class="canvas"></canvas>
<a id="download" style="background: gray; height: 20px; text-align: center; display: block; width: 100px">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling through many searches i found below JS library.

jszip/
jszip-utils
FileSaver.js

using these three i am now able to download multipal file on a single click.